# How to pass multiple values to search in multiple fields over multiple records using multi_match query in Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, graphql

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": [
                "869336","45345345"
              ],
              "type": "phrase_prefix",
              "fields": [
                "id",
                "accountNo",
                "moblileNo"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [],
        "must_not": []
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Need to use multi match query only.I have mentioned some sample fields in the query.I get below error when I run it on postman :
[multi_match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]

Answer (score 1):

For the error that is because `query` only takes a single input string.

It can have multiple values like `"query" : "869336 45345345"` however with the values separated by spaces. How this works, you can probably go through this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

Now looking into your scenario, assuming you'd want to apply [phrase match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase) queries for both the values i.e. `869336` and `45345345`, you just need to separate out the values in its individual [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase) queries.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "869336",
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "fields": [
                  "accountNo",
                  "moblileNo"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "45345345",
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "fields": [
                  "accountNo",
                  "moblileNo"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": []
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [],
              "should": [],
              "must_not": []
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you do not want to apply `phrase_prefix` and instead want to return all the documents having both values in any of the fields, you can simply write the query as below:

```
POST my-multimatch-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "869336 45345345",
                "fields": [
                  "accountNo",
                  "moblileNo"
                ],
                "type": "cross_fields",              <--- Note this
                "operator": "and"                    <--- This would mean only return those documents having both these value. 
              } 
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": []
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [],
              "should": [],
              "must_not": []
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the above comments and how I made use of [cross-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields). Best to go through the links to get better understanding.

Anyways feel free to ask for questions and I hope this helps!

Comment: I have one name string  with spaces and another string at this point how I will differenciate it.

Comment: You can simply make use of single quote something like this `"query": "869336 '45345345 1234'"`

Comment: @AbhijeetSanap If you think your query has been resolved, please upvote and/or accept the answer as mentioned in this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/412539). This would help any other users reading your question understand that the query has been resolved.

Comment: Actually I am getting an issue I have 2 accounts having account name as DCC 1 and DCC 2 .....now I want to find DCC 1 so I am passing query:"'DCC 1'" but getting both results even after giving single quote inside double quote

Comment: First one worked for me. Thank you!! :)